# Testings Directives Controller AngularJS Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I cannot access controllers values, everything is undefined. I can see the values in the log, but cannot access them. Is there a preferred way to creating directives and testing its controllers. I don't want to create a controller with .controller('Ctrl') because then it is a global controller through the whole application, and it could be overwritten.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Widgets.Module')
.directive('ntGrid', [
    'Generator',
    function (Generator) {
        function postLink(scope, jqElm, attr) { }

        function postCompile(tElement, tAttrs) {
            return function postLink2(scope, jqElm, attr) {
                attr.$observe("ntId", function (id) { // called on on init
                    scope.ntId = id !== 'generate' ? id : Generator.id;
                });
            }
        }

        function CtrlGrid(scope, attrs, Generator) {
            var ctrl = scope;

            ctrl.dataStatus = 'No Data';
            ctrl.isLoading = '';
        }

        return {
            template:
                '<div id="{{ ntId }}">' +
                '</div>',
            controller: [
                '$scope', '$attrs', CtrlGrid
            ],
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                ntId: '@'
            },
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: postLink,
            compile: postCompile
        };

    }
])
;
```

This is my test.

```
describe('testing ntGrid', function () {
    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $scope.data = [
            [
                {class: 'description', value: 'Header1'},
                {class: 'description', value: 'Header2'}
            ],
            [
                [
                    {class: 'value', value: '13'},
                    {class: 'smallvalue', value: '6,43%'}
                ],
                {class: 'value', value: '12'},
                {class: 'smallvalue', value: '4,23%'}
            ],
            [
                [
                    {class: 'negativevalue', value: '-13'},
                    {class: 'negativevalue smallvalue', value: '-6,43%'}
                ],
                {class: 'negativevalue', value: '12'},
                {class: 'negativevalue smallvalue', value: '4,23%'}
            ]
        ];
        element = angular.element('<div nt-grid nt-table="data"></div>');
        $compile(element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
        ctrl = element.data('$scope');
    }));

    it('test ntGrid html', inject(function () {

        console.log(ctrl.ntId)
        console.log($scope.ntId)
    }));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I got the scope of a directives controller.

```
var _scope = element.isolateScope();
```